# How to encrypt text so that when decrypting there are 2 (or more) decryption keys with potentially results?

Tags: encryption, decryption

I would like to encrypt text and then publish on the public blockchain (STEEM).

*(I like STEEM because it is easy to use and allows me to store the whole content, rather than just hash when using Bitcoin blockchain)*

I might be coerced into disclosing the encryption phrase, therefore looking for encryption method where 2 *(or more)* passphrases produce human-readable plaintext.

#### Some existing examples of plausible deniability used in practice

**True Crypt**

https://www.truecrypt71a.com/documentation/plausible-deniability/hidden-volume/

**Ledger Nano S**

https://support.ledgerwallet.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005161725-How-to-setup-a-passphrase-and-an-alternate-PIN-

Comment: As the wiki on Deniable Encryption states: _In general, decrypting one ciphertext to multiple plaintexts is not possible unless the key is as large as the plaintext, so this is not practical for most purposes._

Comment: Ha! I didn't know which term to search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption

Comment: @J.A.K. I would also say that if your key as large as the plaintext, nobody will believe your denial. Plus an enemy can decrypt _anything_ they want from your ciphertext, including things that are worse than what you are trying to hide.

Comment: Yes, that is an important point. But the last one is not really a downside in my view, it is exactly what makes a one-time pad so secure. If an adversary knows your key is as long as the ciphertext, he probably won't throw random data together to make you look bad.

Comment: Honey Encryption exists: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_encryption

Answer (score 1):

With a xor based cipher this is trivial.

Message A xor random A' makes ciphertext C, C xor arbitrary message B makes random looking B'. Call A' and B' keys.

A, A', C, B and B' have to be the same used length. This would be most believable as a one time pad; with A' and B' being called pads and having extra length of random bits that aren't used appended.

Using more of A' for future messages might be expected but would mean changing the additional part of B' which if detected is a huge red flag for a one time pad. Also it means you have to secretly store A' which is by definition as hard as hiding A.